# jQuery click on an array of inputs with fixed id

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have multiple input elements like this

```
<input type="submit" name="top[1]" value="A"><br>
<input type="submit" name="top[2]" value="B">
```

the id's are added dynamically. How can I select all input's with name `top[*]` ?

The following jQuery code does not work in my case:

```
$('input[name="top[]"]').click(function(e){
    alert("Hello");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It would  work, if I remove the numbers from the top array. Here is the corresponding [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3mspg6o/). How can I get it working with keeping the fixed id's in my input fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match with regex (the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)):

```
$('input[name^="top"]')
```